# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.x

Here I am trying to import 'libEpsonFiscalDriver.so' file on a Raspberry Pi using Python 2.7.
Here are my steps in python:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/pi/odoo/my_module/escpos/lib/libEpsonFiscalDriver.so')
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/pi/odoo/my_module/escpos/lib/libEpsonFiscalDriver.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Extra Information: Header Information of libEpsonFiscalDriver.so file.

```
$ readelf -h libEpsonFiscalDriver.so 

ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x5de0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          125176 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 26
```

Any help will be more than appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
Machine:                           Intel 80386
```

This shared library object (.so) was compiled for the x86 [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), used predominantly on 32-bit PC style computers with Intel or AMD processors.  All Raspberry Pi models use some variant of [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), which is common in mobile devices.  They are not compatible.

You either have to get the source code and compile it yourself, or else find a version compiled for ARMv6 or 7 (Pi 2 and 3 only).  Since it looks to be a proprietary printer driver, chances are this is not possible, so
you are out of luck.